# Detect Python Indent Start in C#

Tags: c#, regex

I am writing a piece of code to automatically generate indentation in an embedded Python editor, and I am struggling to detect all use cases.

1. `foo` -> no indent on next line
2. `foo:` -> indent
3. `foo: #bar` -> indent
4. `foo: #bar:` -> indent
5. `foo #bar:` -> no indent

So far I have this:

```
Match ColonMatch = Regex.Match(curLineText, @"((:)[^:]*|#.*:)\s*$");
if (ColonMatch.Success && (ColonMatch.Groups.Count == 3) && 
   (ColonMatch.Groups[2].Value == ":"))
{
    // indent on next line
```

This works for all cases except case four.

I don't need to consider C-style comments or multi-line python comments.

Can anyone help with some fancy regex-foo? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually (at least for these 5 cases) you don't need Regular Expressions:

```
curLineText = curLineText.Trim();
bool indent = curLineText.Contains("#")?
              curLineText.Substring(0, curLineText.Length - 1).Contains(":"):
              curLineText.EndsWith(":");
```

**Update:**
I looked at python and `#` is for commenting (didn't know that), so omitting that would give us either it ends with `:` or not. so even simpler:

```
bool indent = curLineText.Split('#')[0].Trim().EndsWith(":");
```